# Can i kill the Webbrowser instance after the link is opened in Chrome?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the Webbrowser in Python to open some links. The link is opening correctly but the program doesn't terminate until I close my Google Chrome browser. That means my program is running until I close my Chrome window. Is this OK or shall I kill/close this webbrowser process using some command?

Comment: Can you please share the code that is doing this?

Comment: I am just taking the links from an excel file and randomly opening a web link.

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your question acoordingly